# Spitting Value From One Field Into Two Values to be Used in Two Different Fields in SQL Server Using SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, dataflow

I have fields in a column with values like the following:

```
ABCDEFG:1234
```

I have a SSIS package that needs to split this value into two values like the following:

```
ABCDEFG

1234
```

The `ABCDEFG` will be imported into Field1 and `1234` into Field2

I have the following script on DerivedColumn1 process in DataFlow:

```
LEFT([PN IN],FINDSTRING([PN IN],":",1))
```

and the following script in DerivedColumn2 process in DataFlow:

```
REPLACE([PN IN],":","")
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
ABCDEFG
```

My question is this...Because I'm already using a derived column for this field, It is not letting me do another DerivedColumn process in my DataFlow to pull the `RIGHT` of the ":" to give me `ABCDEFG`...What protocol do I take to grab the `RIGHT` as well?  Can I nest this into one script?

Comment: I am perplexed: Can't you add the `LEFT` as a new column and the `RIGHT` as another new column in your `Derived Column` component in the `Data Flow Task` ?  How exactly is it not letting you do that?

Comment: Im not trying to create new columns in the DataBase.  I am importing Excel reports that are in one column on the report but need to be split because the DataBase already has the 2 columns that there supposed to be in when split

Answer (score 1):

you can split them like that:

left column:

```
SUBSTRING(col1,1,FINDSTRING(col1,":",1) - 1)
```

right column:

```
SUBSTRING(col1,FINDSTRING(col1,":",1) + 1,LEN(col1) - FINDSTRING(col1,":",1))
```

or, if you have `SSIS 2012`, you can use the TOKEN function

left column: `TOKEN(col1,":",1)`
right column: `TOKEN(col1,":",2)`

Comment: I Can grab the LEFT and RIGHT.  Perhaps I should of asked a better question. I currently have an "ExcelSource" pointing to a "Derived Column" pointing to an "OLE DB Command".  All my variables are mapped to the columns in my ExcelSource.  My problem is in my DataFlow process.  The column Im splitting up needs to be mapped to 2 different collumns in the DataBase.  What steps do I need to take in my DataFlow process to take the LEFT and RIGHT and put each into two seperate fields in the DataBase when the Field in my ExcelSource can only be mapped to one variable in my OLE DB Command?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Derived Columns]

I didn't even find this `LEFT` function in my SSIS, but if you could elaborate on what it is not letting you do, maybe somebody can help you out...

Comment: "LEFT" is in the newer version of SSIS

Comment: Im trying to do another DerivedColumn to grab the "RIGHT".  But because there is already a DerivedColumn that grabs the "LEFT".  The RIGHT is now non-existant...If I try to do another DerivedColumn after the first one to grab the RIGHT, it will not let me add the field that I need to add.

Comment: Figured as much, I've only got the 2008 R2 kicking around.  Regardless, what I'm doing in my screenshot does not consume the [LoginName] column I'm dummy running.  I'd have to see the new SSIS to figure out why your column is being consumed.  Maybe try SUBSTRING on both?  I use that all the time for parsing nasty text files.